# Are these two fields $\mathbb {F}_{p}(x)$ and $\mathbb {F}_{p}(x^p)$ are isomorphic fields?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Are these two fields $\mathbb {F}_{p}(x)$ and $\mathbb {F}_{p}(x^p)$ are isomorphic fields?

Only thing I know there exists embeddings from one field to another and the extension $\mathbb {F}_{p}(x)/\mathbb {F}_{p}(x^p)$ is Galois with Galois group cyclic of order $p$. I don’t know if I have to really use these information. Help me. Thanks.

Comment: This extension is not Galois, because the extension is not seperable. The minimal polynomial of $x$ in $\mathbb{F}_p(x^p)$ is $(t-x)^p = t^p-x^p$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathbb{F}_p(x)$ and $\mathbb{F}_p(x^p)$ are both purely transcendental extensions of $\mathbb{F}_p$ and they both have transcendence degree $1$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$. Because purely transcendental extensions of the same transcendence degree are isomorphic, these two are isomorphic (see for example [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-782-introduction-to-arithmetic-geometry-fall-2013/lecture-notes/MIT18_782F13_lec12.pdf) page 2, shortly after Definition 12.3).